# url repair function for previous directory "../" eats domain name

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting

I've had this function for some time:

```
function fixLink($url){
    return preg_replace('@/[^/]+/\.\./@','/',$url);
}
```

and it worked wonders for turning:
 `http://domain.com/page/../index.html` into `http://domain.com/index.html`
but recently I had to use it on:
 `http://domain.com/../index.html` and result was `http://index.html`

How do I safeguard the domain name in this case so it outputs the repaired link as: `http://domain.com/index.html` ?

Looking for ideas on how to tackle the problem, please don't go overboard with code.

Comment: What *should* that expand to? `/../index.html` is invalid, since you can't go up from `/`.

Comment: `http://domain.com/index.html`, it's indeed used on an _invalid url_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function fixLink($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (empty($parts['path']) || empty($parts['scheme'])) {
        return $url;
    }
    $parts['path'] = preg_replace('@[^/]+/\.\./@', '', $parts['path']);
    $parts['path'] = preg_replace('@^/\.\./@', '/', $parts['path']);
    $parts['scheme'] .= '://';
    return implode('', $parts);
}
```

However, the above doesn't solve all situations. A more robust version would be:

```
function fixLink($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (empty($parts['scheme']) || empty($parts['path'])) {
        return $url;
    }
    $path = array();
    foreach (explode('/', $parts['path']) as $i => $item) {
        if ($item == '..') {
            if (count($path) > 1) {
                array_pop($path);
            }
        } else {
            $path[] = $item;
        }    
    }
    $parts['scheme'] .= '://';
    $parts['path'] = implode('/', $path);
    return implode('', $parts);
}
```

Comment: really malformed url to test: `http://www.123.com/sdf/../../kjsdf/../../../s.txt`